# SQL COUNT(*) OVER() in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How do you translate the below SQL into Python, specifically the count(*) OVER() portion? I need to display the total count of userIDs not as a single value but as the same value for each userID row, so I can do Ct/Total_Ct and display each userID's rate.

```
select userID, count(*) as Ct, count(*) OVER() AS Total_Ct
from cte
group by userID
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
userID   Ct  Total_Ct
A1       5      7 
A2       3      7 
A3       1      7 
A4       2      7 
A5       5      7 
A6       6      7 
A7       4      7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way you can translate this query easily to Python:

```
data['total_users'] = data['userID'].count()

total_rows_for_user = data.groupby('userID').size().reset_index().rename(columns = {'size':'total_rows_for_user'})

data = data.merge(total_rows_for_user, on='userID')
```

Comment: Note that this is Pandas code, not SQL.

Comment: That's what he asked for, no ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is the version you want:

```sql
SELECT userID, COUNT(*) AS ct, SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS Total_Ct
FROM cte
GROUP BY userID;
```

Keep in mind that in a `GROUP BY` query, the window functions operate over the aggregated intermediate table.  So `COUNT(*) OVER ()` just counts the number of distinct users, but `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()` counts the total number of records in the original table.

Regarding running the above SQL from Python, you would need to use a raw query.  It would likely not work directly from an ORM layer.

Comment: No, `COUNT(*) OVER()` is commonly used to count the total number of groups (total rows produced by group by). If I applied SUM to `COUNT(*) OVER()`, the resulting value is incorrect. What does using a raw query look like? I am quite new to python.

Comment: @tj1 That entirely depends on what library you are using to access the database. You'll need to provide more details about what you have so far (if anything) to get a better answer. If you don't have anything, you'll need to start by learning about database access in Python.